# Codigo PHP no se ejecuta

Tags: php, apache2, localhost, sintaxis

El código de la pagina es el siguiente:

```
<?php
   echo '<h1>CONEXION CON POO</h1>';
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','supermarket');

   echo '<h1>CONEXION CON POO</h1>';
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo '<p>Ha ocurrido un error al conectarse a la DDBB</p>';
      exit;
   } else {
      echo '<h2>Se realizo la conexion</h2>';
      $mysqli->set_charset('uft8');
      $query = 'SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS';

      $result = $mysqli->query($query);

      $user = $result->fetch_array();
      echo "<p>$user[0]</p>";
   }
?>
```

Es un código muy simple, lo que pasa es que en mi localhost, me muestra la pagina pero solo hasta el primer `echo '<h1>CONEXION CON POO</h1>';` luego de eso no me imprime nada mas, habiendo un segundo `echo` 2 lineas de código después.

Los datos de la base de datos los revise y son los correctos, y ya intente también reemplazando `localhost` por `127.0.0.1`, mi archivo termina en extension .php, el localhost esta en funcionamiento, y error de sintaxis no veo que haya.
Alguien sabe si no tengo alguna librería instalada o algo así?

Gracias de antemano. Diego

Comment: Muestra errores y warnings y dinos qué te sale. Agrega las tres líneas que se comentan aquí: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-errors-in-php-file al inicio de tu script

Comment: Intenta con `mysqli_connect`. `$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','supermarket');`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que quiero concectarme a la ddbb con POO en lo posible, porque con programacion orientada a procedimientos ya lo hice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, la solucion al error era no tener instalado mysqli, desconozco la razón de esto pero bastó con ejecutar la siguiente linea en la temrinal:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysqlnd
```

Comment: No es MySQLi lo que te faltaba sino mysqlnd

Answer (score 0):

Por que no intentas utilizar el concepto de PDO [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php) para una Programación Orientada a Objetos es mas conveniente sobre todo por el tema "deprecated"  en las nuevas versiones.

Un ejemplo real en uso:

```
class BD {
private $pdo=null;
private static $host="localhost";
private static $user="root";
private static $password="";
protected $bd="tu_base_de_datos";  //cambie este dato

protected function conectar(){
    try{
        @$dsn="mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->bd;
        $this->pdo=new PDO($dsn, self::$user, self::$password);
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        print "Error!: No se pudo conectar a la bd ".$this->bd."<br/>";
        die();
    }
} }
```

Te dejo un tutorial de referencia: [Tutorial PDO](https://diego.com.es/tutorial-de-pdo) donde te explica paso a paso como llegar al código anterior, es probable que no sea 100% similar este es una adaptación local de donde trabajo, pero si sigues esta sencilla explicación te aseguro que te funciona sin problema tu conexión de bases de datos.
Existen muchos mas tutoriales si este no te convence.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, pero quiero intentarlo con POO en lo posible, de todas formas mas adelante vere con PDO.

Comment: @Diegono entiendo tu comentario pues quien te respondió lo hizo aplicando POO